# Batch move files based on part of file name - Windows 8

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I've got a number of files I'm trying to sort through for my PhD research. I'm not familiar with using Batch files but I do have some coding experience.

I'm trying to move the files based on part of their filename into folders generated automatically for them in the directory they're currently in.

The files were generated as part of a series of pXRF analyses on brass objects held at a museum.

Some examples of the file structure:

- 01-64.1007-1-LID.pdz
- 01-64.1007-2-BASE.pdz
- 02-67.1765-1.pdz
- 02-67.1765-2.pdz
- 02-67.1765-3.pdz

etc.

Basically the file structure works like this:

The first number is my unique identifier for the object, then a hyphen, then the museums unique identifier, then a hyphen, then a number to show which analysis of the object. Finally, there may or may not be a small descriptor (i.e. BASE or LID) which helps me identify where I performed the scan.

So to break it down 01-64.1007-1-LID means Object 1 - Museum Accession Number 64.1007 - First Analysis - Performed on the lid of the object - .pdz is the file extension.

02-67.1765-2 means Object 2 - Museum Accession Number 67.1765 - Second Analysis etc.

What I want to do is move:

- 01-64.1007-1-LID.pdz
- 01-64.1007-2-BASE.pdz

into a folder called:

- 01-64.1007

and

- 02-67.1765-1.pdz
- 02-67.1765-2.pdz
- 02-67.1765-3.pdz

into a folder called:

- 02-67.1765

etc.

I've seen a few scripts which may help with this but I'm unsure how to tweak them for my purposes. If anyone can help I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html http://ss64.com/nt/md.html http://ss64.com/nt/move.html

Comment: Do you want to use a windows-like .bat script or a linux-like .sh script? Why don't you use the language you already have experience in?

Comment: I'd like to use a windows .bat file - my coding experience is limited to very specific applications for my PhD and generally involved building plugins for an app, editing or modifying code provided by others (quite a bit of LUA, a bit of stuff in Qt Creator for a database viewer). I've just started learning Ruby on Rails for a web app I'm building but that's in the very early days - I'm an archaeologist we're generally Luddites unfortunately :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this batch file in a folder of sample files: call it `movepdz.bat` so the name doesn't clash with another executable.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.pdz) do (
   echo processing "%%a"
      for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%b in ("%%~nxa") do (
         md "%%b-%%c" 2>nul
         move "%%a" "%%b-%%c" >nul
      )
)
pause
```

Comment: Could you please add a short explanation to your answer. (I'm usually not the windows batch guy, especially when it comes to things like `("%%~nxa")`.)

Comment: Ok, that's definitely got legs! It moved the files properly but unfortunately it got the folder names wrong. It stopped at the first hypen rather than the second. So the folder structure goes 01, 02, 03 etc. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't notice the first hyphen - try the edited code above.

Comment: @michas Please ask a question about which aspect you need clarification on.

Comment: Working perfectly now. It's a thing of beauty - you've just saved me about 15 hours of work! Thanks!

Comment: @foxidrive Is it possible to give variables a meaningful name? What exactly is `"%%~nxa"` doing? Where does the variable `%%c` come from? - Sure it is possible to research all this, but it would be nice if there would be a few words explaining your code.

Comment: @michas: there is a nice explanation built in `for /?`

Comment: The for `metavariables` cannot have descriptive names and `%%~nxa` separates the `%%a` metavariable into the `name.extension` which in this case is exactly the same as `%%a`.  I used it in case subdirectories needed to be processed, though other changes are still needed for that case. `for /?` will show you the help and the last page lists the modifiers.  The `tokens=1,2` gives you two tokens which are split at the delimiter.  Each is allocated a name in Ascii order starting with the `for metavariable` that is used.  `%%b` in that line so `%%c` is next and then `%%d` etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you really mean a bash script, you can use something like this:

```
for file in *.pdz; do
  dir=${echo "$file"|cut -d- -f -2}
  mkdir -p "$dir"
  mv "$file" "$dir"
done
```

The `cut` command will cut out the part before the second hyphen to determine the directory name. Then we create the directory in case it is not already present. Finally simply move the file in that directory.

Update: Thanks for clarifying your environment. (I was sure the question mentioned bash before...) - If you want to use this solution you could install [git](http://git-scm.com/) which comes with a nice git-bash.

Comment: I'm being incredibly dense here - I apologise (long night - I was up until 3am and I've been working from 8am this morning). I copy this into notepad, save it as a .bat file and run the .bat right? If that's correct it doesn't seem to be doing anything unfortunately.

Comment: this is bash - different from batch. Although some commands look the same, the syntax is not the same. in general: Windows=batch, Unix=bash

Comment: @Stephan, yes, the question used to mention bash, therefore my initial comment on the question and the update to this answer.

Comment: @michas my comment was meant to explain the difference to Michael as it might not be obvious to him. I should have added "@Michael"